# Windows mobile look on Windows CE 5

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

Since 2004 I've been developing a Windows Pocket PC application using the Compact Framework (currently at version 3.5). The program has been used on devices such as HP iPaq 214 and relatively expensive Psion Walkabout Pro hardware.

We would like to support more devices having RFID reading capability and is currently looking at a device using Windows CE 5, that is, *without* the Mobile 6 'overlay'. I'm able to install the program and its requirements on the CE device. I'm also able to run and use the program.

However, CE uses other UI standards than Mobile. My brief testing showed

- The menu is placed at the top - not the bottom.
- There is the standard windows decoration.
- The start button, systray etc. is visible.

My question is: Is it possible to set some parameters to get Windows Mobile 'looks' when the program runs in Windows CE?

Preferably it should work cross platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking if it's possible to modify some parameters at the OS level to make it look like WM, the answer is 'No'. If you want a consistent look across both platforms, you'll have to create a full-screen application and provide the UI within your application yourself.

Comment: I'll update the post with information on what steps I took in order to keep WM and CE as aligned as possible within my time limits.

Answer (score 0):

My non-perfect solution ended up as follows.

During initialization I detect whether it is a Windows Mobile system or vanilla Windows CE. If it is a Windows CE system I use the following during setup of the main form

```
Bounds = new Rectangle(-5, -25, 250, 330)
```

This moves the window decorations out of view and leaves a client area similar (I have not pixel counted so I cannot say if they are equal) to the client area available on Windows Mobile.

However, I've not found a way of moving the menu to the bottom as of yet.